How can I "register" a software as "Windows App"
When I install something from particular sources, that software is interpreted as a Windows App.
PowerToys Run fetching "windows apps" using the "Programs" plugin
From other sources, I guess it's seen as just a piece of software
PowerToys fetches files and folders using "Windows Search" plugin
So how can I make any random software a "real boy" a.k.a. Windows App?
The ideal answer would be 'there is a way, here's how' or 'there's just no way'.
I guess I would accept a recommendation of a launcher that let me easily (no coding, wearing too tight underwear etc.) either pick a folder with a bunch of shortcuts without messing with windows indexing options, or whitelist a couple file types instead of blacklisting hundreds of filetypes. But yea, ideally I would like to know if it's possible or not.
I tried to web search but couldn't find any answers, I might just not know how to word it so I can't get any relevant results.

"no coding" questions are off topic for this site. This is a coding site.
